# Хранение даты в MySQL (не в time)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Проект на PHP даты в нем храню time(). Однако в ходе разработки столкнулся с вопросом, что в некоторых случаях пользователь может ввести в БД MySQL дату к примеру 01.01.1940, а time() насколько я знаю это отсчет от 01.01.1970. Вот и возник вопрос как в данном случае хранить, читать, делать отчеты? Как я понимаю использовать char для хранения это не вариант.

Comment: А чем datetime MySQLевский не угодил?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html

Comment: *даты ... храню time() ... ввести в БД MySQL* В MySQL нет типа данных  `time()`.

Comment: Я имел ввиду при записи в БД в коде PHP пишу что то вроде $table->date = time();